# Angular - Dependent Field Validation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, select

I got a problem. I'm trying to create a validation directive for my form. My validation process is a bit complex. I got 4 selects (dropdowns). 2 dropdowns for a first team (user and deputy) and the same for a second team.

My validation directive needs to do the following:

1. User first team selected but not a deputy first team (require deputy first team)
2. Deputy first team selected but not a user first team (require user first team)
3. User second team selected but not a deputy second team (require deputy second team)
4. Deputy second team selected but not a user second team (require user second team)
5. No user nor deputy for first or second team selected (require at least one user or deputy)

My html looks like this:

```
        <div class="row" ng-form="reportForm" ng-model="report" require-users>                
            <!-- User First Team -->
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>User First Team</label>
                    <!-- Dropdown User First Team -->
                    <select ng-form="reportForm.userFirst" 
                            ng-model="report.userFirst" 
                            ng-options="user.Name for user in users track by user.Id" 
                            class="form-control">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>

                    <!-- Error Messages-->
                    <div ng-messages="reportForm.$error" style="color:maroon; margin-top: 4px;" role="alert">
                        <!-- Message required -->
                        <div ng-message="requireUserFirst">
                            <small>A User for the first team is required.</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Deputy First Team -->
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Deputy First Team</label>
                    <!-- Dropdown Deputy First Team -->
                    <select ng-form="reportForm.deputyFirst" 
                            ng-model="report.deputyFirst" 
                            ng-options="user.Name for user in users track by user.Id" 
                            class="form-control">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>

                     <!-- Error messages -->
                    <div ng-messages="reportForm.$error" style="color:maroon; margin-top: 4px;" role="alert">
                        <!-- Message required -->
                        <div ng-message="requireDeputyFirst">
                            <small>A Deputy for the first team is required.</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- User Second Team -->
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>User Second Team</label>
                    <!-- Dropdown User Second Team -->
                    <select ng-form="reportForm.userSecond" 
                            ng-model="report.userSecond" 
                            ng-options="user.Name for user in users track by user.Id" 
                            class="form-control">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>

                     <!-- Error messages -->
                    <div ng-messages="reportForm.$error" style="color:maroon; margin-top: 4px;" role="alert">
                       <!-- Message required -->
                        <div ng-message="requireUserSecond">
                            <small>A User for the second team is required.</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Deputy Second Team -->
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Deputy Second Team</label>
                    <!-- Dropdown Deputy Second Team -->
                    <select ng-form="reportForm.deputySecond" 
                            ng-model="report.deputySecond" 
                            ng-options="user.Name for user in users track by user.Id" 
                            class="form-control">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>

                     <!-- Error messages -->
                    <div ng-messages="reportForm.$error" style="color:maroon; margin-top: 4px;" role="alert">
                        <!-- Message required -->
                        <div ng-message="requireDeputySecond">
                            <small>A Deputy for the second team is required.</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Error messages -->
            <div ng-messages="reportForm.$error" style="color:maroon; margin-top: 4px;" role="alert" class="col-xs-12">
                <!-- Message missing user and deputy -->
                <div ng-message="requireAll">
                    <small><strong>At least one user and deputy is needed.</strong></small>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
```

And my directive is here:

```
app.directive('requireUsers', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModel.$modelValue;
            }, function (model, oldModel) {
                if (model != oldModel) {

                    if (model.userFirst == null && model.deputyFirst == null && model.userSecond == null && model.deputySecond == null) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireAll', false);
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireAll', true);
                    }

                    if ((model.userFirst == undefined || model.userFirst == null) && model.deputyFirst != null) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireUserFirst', false);
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireUserFirst', true);
                    }

                    if ((model.deputyFirst == undefined || model.deputyFirst == null) && model.userFirst != null) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireDeputyFirst', false);
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireDeputyFirst', true);
                    }

                    if ((model.userSecond == undefined || model.userSecond == null) && model.deputySecond != null) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireUserSecond', true);
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireUserSecond', true);
                    }

                    if ((model.deputySecond == undefined || model.deputySecond == null) && model.userSecond != null) {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireDeputySecond', false);
                    } else {
                        ngModel.$setValidity('requireDeputySecond', true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**The problem is that the watcher doesn't work only when the directive gets initialized. So when I change a value the validation process won't get started.**

**UPDATE ReportController:**

```
angular.module('ReportTool')
    .controller('ReportController', ['$scope', 'Report', 'User', function ($scope, Report, User) {
        var _this = this;

        // Load all Teammembers (API Call in Service)
        User.query().then(function (success) {
            _this.users= success.data;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Users could not be loaded.');
        });            

        // Save report
        this.save = function () {
            if (_this.report != null) {
                // create report
                Report.post(_this.report).then(function (success) {
                    console.log('Report created.');
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log('Report could not be created.');
            } else {
                console.log('Report is null.');
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Can you add your controller as well or make a plunker?

Comment: Probably, you should use the directive `requireUsers` to each **INPUT** and **SELECT**.

Comment: @dendimiiii for what do you need the controller exactly?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko If I do this I can't read the other users or deputies because the ng-model is different on each of the SELECT elements.

Comment: To make a plunker myself :)

Comment: @dendimiiii I added my controller. There is not much in there ;)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to write a directive for each check, like the `requireUsers`.

I recommend using directive [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error).
With it easy to create custom checks.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/2avu5s9s/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['use', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  });
```

```css
.errors {
  color: maroon
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error/master/src/use-form-error.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <form name="myForm">
      <label>User first:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="userFirst" name="userFirst" use-form-error="requireUserFirst" use-error-expression="!userFirst && deputyFirst" />
      <br>
      <label>Deputy first:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="deputyFirst" name="deputyFirst" use-form-error="requireDeputyFirst" use-error-expression="userFirst && !deputyFirst"/>
      <br>
      <hr>

      <label>User second:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="userSecond" name="userSecond" />
      <br>
      <label>Deputy second:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="deputySecond" name="deputySecond" />
      <br>

      <div use-form-error="requireAll" use-error-expression="!userFirst && !deputyFirst && !userSecond && !deputySecond" use-error-input="myForm"> </div>
      <div ng-messages="myForm.$error" class="errors">
        <div ng-message="requireAll">At least one user and deputy is needed.</div>
      </div>
      <div ng-messages="myForm.userFirst.$error" class="errors">
        <div ng-message="requireUserFirst">A User for the first team is required.</div>
      </div>
      <div ng-messages="myForm.deputyFirst.$error" class="errors">
        <div ng-message="requireDeputyFirst">A Deputy for the first team is required.</div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way to only do it with one directive? Like I did on the require-users directive? It would be a lot easier for me to just put the directive in one element instead inside of each select. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I'm added another answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple pass your variable into your `directive`. And then check it.

Live examplee on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/xpLz4b16/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  })
  .directive('requireUsers', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'form',
      scope: {
        userFirst: "=",
        deputyFirst: "=",
        userSecond: "=",
        deputySecond: "=",
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
        function changeValue(model, oldModel) {
          if (!scope.userFirst && !scope.deputyFirst && !scope.userSecond && !scope.deputySecond) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireAll', false);
          } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireAll', true);
          }

          if (!scope.userFirst && scope.deputyFirst) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireUserFirst', false);
          } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireUserFirst', true);
          }

          if (!scope.deputyFirst && scope.userFirst) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireDeputyFirst', false);
          } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireDeputyFirst', true);
          }

          if (!scope.userSecond && scope.deputySecond) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireUserSecond', false);
          } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireUserSecond', true);
          }

          if (!scope.deputySecond && scope.userSecond) {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireDeputySecond', false);
          } else {
            ngModel.$setValidity('requireDeputySecond', true);
          }
        }
        scope.$watch('userFirst', changeValue);
        scope.$watch('deputyFirst', changeValue);
        scope.$watch('userSecond', changeValue);
        scope.$watch('deputySecond', changeValue);
      }
    };
  });;
```

```css
.errors {
  color: maroon
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <form name="myForm" require-users user-first="userFirst" deputy-first="deputyFirst" user-second="userSecond" deputy-second="deputySecond">
      <label>User first:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="userFirst" name="userFirst" />
      <br>
      <label>Deputy first:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="deputyFirst" name="deputyFirst" />
      <br>
      <hr>

      <label>User second:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="userSecond" name="userSecond" />
      <br>
      <label>Deputy second:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="deputySecond" name="deputySecond" />
      <br>


      <div ng-messages="myForm.$error" class="errors">
        <div ng-message="requireAll">At least one user and deputy is needed.</div>
        <div ng-message="requireUserFirst">A User for the first team is required.</div>
        <div ng-message="requireDeputyFirst">A Deputy for the first team is required.</div>
        <div ng-message="requireUserSecond">A User for the second team is required.</div>
        <div ng-message="requireDeputySecond">A Deputy for the second team is required.</div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being picky but I think this solution is not clean because you have to "concatenate" the model. I believe there is a better solution. Maybe do you know why my watcher only gets executed once even though I change the model? Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Your watcher watch only to change value of your value of **FORM**! In code `return ngModel.$modelValue` you tell watch on change value of **form**. Your **form** value is not the same as `ng-model` in your **input** and **select**.

Comment: I'm update jsfiddle. It now without "concatenate" the model.

Comment: Why does it take the form? I wrote ng-model="report" shouldn't it take this as the ngModel in the directive?

Comment: You use `directive` `require-users` in tag **<form>**. And then using `ngModel`. Directive pick the **FORM**, because you initialize directive in form. Your `ng-model='report'` not have directive `require-users`. More detail about [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).